# When did Opening Credits become Closing Credits?

Tags: credits

Can anyone point me to the exact (or close) movie or time period that began listing lengthy closing credits?  I've seen plenty of B&W movies (and probably a few color ones) where all the credits were in the beginning and only a handful were at the end.

For extra credit, if anyone knows **why** that switch was made, I'd be interested to hear that too.

Comment: For extra credit to the asker it would be an even greater question if the extra credit wasn't an extra but a full part of the question in the first place. ;-)

Comment: It was something to do with the unions demanding all those who worked on the film were acknowledged in the credits, making for a long tedious opening so they were moved to the end of the movie

Comment: You can only make a first impression once, and most people decide subconciously if they like a movie in the first few seconds. They should drop everything from the start, including producing company. Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn who earns money wih he movie I am going to watch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, a quick [Wikipedia check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits) produced this nugget, which answers part of the question:

> The use of closing credits in film to list complete production crew
>   and cast was not firmly established in American film until the 1970s.
>   Before this decade, most movies were released with no closing credits
>   at all. Films generally had opening credits only, which consisted of
>   just major cast and crew, although sometimes the names of the cast and
>   the characters they played would be shown at the end, as in The Wizard
>   of Oz, Mary Poppins, Oliver! and the 1964 Fail Safe. Two of the first
>   major films to contain extensive closing credits – but almost no
>   opening credits – were the blockbusters Around the World in 80 Days
>   (1956) and West Side Story (1961). West Side Story showed only the
>   title at the beginning of the film, and Around the World in 80 Days,
>   like many films today, had no opening credits at all.

And this came from a separate [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opening_credits), which answers the "Extra Credit" portion of the question:

> The ascendancy of television movies after 1964 and the increasingly
>   short "shelf-life" of films in theaters has largely contributed to the
>   credits convention which came with television programs from the
>   beginning, of holding the vast majority of cast and crew information
>   for display at the end of the show.

Comment: Can't help feeling there's more to it, I can remember watching a documentary, (probably early/mid 90's, BBC? CH4?) about the history of cinema (along those lines) that covered in detail my earlier comment. But the mists of time.......

Comment: Interesting. So there should be some exact year when those lengthy end credits appeared.  I'll have to do some more digging.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen in other movies.stackexchange.com questions, the transition from the "studio system" (actors, etc., directly under contract to the studios) to a more independent system (late 50s/early 60s) probably contributed to this a lot. See [Why do movies still have credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18062/why-do-movies-still-have-credits?rq=1)

Comment: Do you have any examples that could support your answer?