# Most recent Hollywood feature film without closing credits

Tags: credits, cinema-history, american-cinema

From the discussion at "[When did Opening Credits become Closing Credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24851/19812)", we learn that "the use of closing credits in film to list complete production crew and cast was not firmly established in American film until the 1970s. Before this decade, most movies were released with no closing credits at all."

What is the most recent Hollywood feature-length film not to contain closing credits at all?  Since the 1970s, have there been any "retro"-style movies that used opening credits only, similar to how we nowadays see the occasional modern film that is [silent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Movie) or [black-and-white](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schindler's_List) (or [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Artist_%28film%29))?

Comment: There are two questions here. In answer to the retro-style question, the answer is yes.

Comment: @sanpaco: The first question subsumes the second.  If you know of a recent Hollywood feature film, retro-style or otherwise, that has no closing credits, then please name it in an answer.

Comment: The problem is that it may not be able to pass union rules to exclude the credits... It means people's work is getting shown without crediting them.

Comment: You are asking a) what is the most recent movie to not have closing credits, and b) what are some movies that have used retro style opening credits. The presences of one does not preclude the other. There are very well movies out there that have stylistic opening credits but also have closing credits.

Comment: @sanpaco: Please reread the second question.  It definitely does exclude movies with closing credits.

Comment: @Catija: I am not asking about movies without any credits.  I am asking about movies without _closing_ credits.  Are you aware of any union rules that require credits to be placed at the end of the movie, rather than at the beginning?

Comment: No one is going to accept 10 minutes of credits for every single best boy grip and office intern before the film starts. Before end credits, very few people outside of cast and department heads were listed in the credits. Now, everyone is.

Comment: Answers to this question are going to become out of date as soon as a new qualifying film comes out.

Comment: @Hugo: And I imagine such films are exceedingly rare.  Absent a massive shift in credit styles and union agreements, whatever the most recent qualifying film is now will probably remain so for many years to come—perhaps even forever.

Comment: Did *Man on the Moon* have closing credits? I remember it having long opening credits contrary to what @Catija said. Granted it was employed as a kind of exposition/plot element. It has been so long since I've seen the movie I am not sure if the credits played again at the end in a non plot driven manner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last Hollywood movie I found with no end credits is *Apocalypse Now* (1979):

> I have always felt the movie to be the very best depiction we will ever see of the insanity of war. I actually saw it on a huge screen back in 1979 when it was first released, and it was mind-boggling - even moreso at the time. It was playing at one of the last huge cinema theatres left in my city. **When it first played, it was released with no end credits at all. Instead, we were given printed programs containing all the credits. So the movie ended with "the horror, the horror" and then the loud sound of the rain over the river and very slow fade-out. I will always remember the awed silence of the audience as we left the theatre.** Another reason it was so mind-blowing at the time is that surround sound had just been created in theatres, so the sound was a stunning new dimension. I was so blown away by the movie, I hid in a washroom stall and snuck back in to see it a second time right away. It was one of the most memorable viewing experiences I have ever had.

[KelMHill, "Apocalypse Now, which cut is better?", /r/movies](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/4kgsjg/apocalypse_now_which_cut_is_better/d3f33ep/?st=iwxcg3kz&sh=cc74b94f)